# How to process this condition in r programming?

Tags: r, functional-programming

There is a table with 3 columns

```
Id Food Sex

1       23       0
2       46       1
3       99       1
4       37       0
5       12       1
```

Now how do I get mean of food whose sex is marked as 1?

I have applied `if(data$sex == 1)`
To check the conditions but how do I select food column to get mean of food with the help of sex column

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(Sex ==1) %>% select(Food) %>% unlist() %>% mean(.)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `summarise`, instead of `unlist` and `mean`?

Comment: I used to handle such issues with this syntaxe avoiding NA troubles. Sometimes I prefer the use of mutate to store the mean. Here it is not mentioned if the value has to be stored of just displayed